# Spring Boot JPA update after fething ID is not working

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

```
@Autowired
LessonService lsnService;

    @PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateLesson(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid @RequestBody LessonDto dto) {
        try {
            lsnService.findById(id);
            dto.setId(id);
            lsnService.save(dto);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(dto);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ApiErrorMessage errorMessage = new ApiErrorMessage();
            errorMessage.setStatusCode(400L);
            errorMessage.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            errorMessage.setDescription("The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Here's my problem. When I remove `lsnService.findById(id);`, update is working.

If I didn't add that code if a user update with unexisting ID, it will save another data. 
Another problem is when I remove `dto.setId(id);`, both method from lsnService; `findById(id);` and `save(dto);` are working! But as you can see, repo must update the entity but it won't!!!

So, I tried to put `@Transactional` in saving. And I even try putting `Thread.sleep(5000);` 5 secs delay between those two services. Like this,

```
lsnService.findById(id);
Thread.sleep(5000);
dto.setId(id);
lsnService.save(dto);
```

But it doesn't work either!

```
    @Autowired
    private LessonJpaRepository repo;

    @Override
    public LessonDto findById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Lesson lesson = repo.getOne(id);
        LessonDto dto = new LessonDto(lesson);
        return dto;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(LessonDto dto) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repo.save(dto.getEntity());
        System.out.println(dto.getId()+dto.getTitle()+dto.getStructure()+dto.getExplanation());
    }
```

And then, I check output of that dto. It's all there! repo is not saving it! It's so strange to me. Got any ideas?

```
public class LessonDto {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "Title must not be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Title must not be blank")
    @ValidLessonTitle(message = "Title must begin with uppercase character")
    private String title;

    @NotNull(message = "Structure must not be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Structure must not be blank")
    private String structure;

    @NotNull(message = "Explanation must not be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Explanation must not be blank")
    private String explanation;

    public LessonDto() {

    }

    public LessonDto(Lesson lesson) {
        this.id=lesson.getId();
        this.title=lesson.getTitle();
        this.structure=lesson.getStructure();
        this.explanation=lesson.getExplanation();
    }

    @java.beans.Transient
    public Lesson getEntity() {
        Lesson lesson = new Lesson();
        lesson.setId(this.id);
        lesson.setTitle(this.title);
        lesson.setStructure(this.structure);
        lesson.setExplanation(this.explanation);
        return lesson;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

This is the entity

```
@Entity
public class Lesson implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2239534946567783017L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "structure")
    private String structure;

    @Column(name = "explanation")
    private String explanation;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what are you trying to achieve and what problem are you facing? So that we can help.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I'm trying to update.

Comment: Can you update the question with LessonDto class?

Comment: @GaneshHoolageri there you go, man!

Comment: All bros, also note that using Transcient annotation is to neglect it in the json body. I tried removing it and the problem is NOT because of that annotation and I need help.

Comment: Its not working because..... ?? Everytime you state something is working/not working you have to explain what is actually happening - eg. exception i thrown, error something is (not) done etc.

Comment: Altough it should call merge under the hood (and update only diff) the most viable way that MUST work will the be to fetch entity from DB and update that entity with values from DTO. In your case entity and DTO are of the same class but that does not matter.

Comment: @Antoniossss You mean like this? Not working!!! `LessonDto out = lsnService.findById(id); out.setTitle(dto.getTitle()); out.setStructure(dto.getStructure()); out.setExplanation(dto.getExplanation()); lsnService.save(out);`

Comment: Yes. It is also worth mentioning that last save is not needed. Changes will be commited with or without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to make that work

1. Update instance that is retured by `findById` with values from DTO
2. Dont use `findById` as it fetches entity pointer (at least) to the cache and this might be the origin of problems. Try to use `existsById` instead

Comment: I tried both and still not working!!! You told me the most possible ways of errors. Thanks for your help anyway! I appreciate that!

Comment: Nah, using first option is literally impossible to fail without exception.

Comment: The only way I can think of is that you are rolling back the transaction somehow somewhere.

Comment: Why would I lie to you, man? The first options didn't work! But the second does! I misunderstood that you want `findById` to rename it into `existsById` Sorry. The second option works! Many thanks your help! It's working now! You should have told me clearly `existsById` from Repository! Cuz I'm showing you the Service Layer, Heee heeee! You're my hero!

Comment: Its not that you lie - it can be other factors like eg. human error.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about that! Thanks to you!!! You made my day! God bless you, man!

Comment: +offtopic if your `lsnService` only delegates to repository method without additional logic, there is no point of having it :)

Comment: I have just noticed what are you doing in your service layer (i blindly assumet it is just @Repository due to cloned method names) and what you are doing there is kind of bad as you are not taking leverage of managed entities anywahre (thus FIRST option does not work - I assumed it returns MANAGED ENTITY not hand-made DTO). You will have more problems like that in future.

Comment: It's not necessary but I think it's a good practice because sometimes Hibernate can throw LazyInitizationException when I make relationship with other entity and requested the one which session is closed. So putting it in a DTO `new Dto(Entity);` or a new Object overcome that problem. Also if I want to make change of something, I can do it without touching the entity.

Comment: You "overcomed" 1 problem and created another (and more incoming). Just a suggestion - revisit your approach. Throwing away whole JPA framework just to catch 1 exception in the service layer is not something you can consider a good practice. Without your "fix" 1) Method 1 would work, 2) method 2 would still work 3) you would not have a problem in the first place as your original approach would work as well (if throw away dto and use plain entity).

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions. I do appreciate that. I'll definitely take consider what you've suggested me to think about that.